# How to stream a video in realtime using python

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming

I'm using python to stream a video stored over the server. Before streaming, I'm drawing some rectangle in each frame using OpenCV then I have to stream the frame. So we can play the live streaming video using VLC or other players.

The question is, how to send each frame so VLC player can play the video?

Comment: You can create a new video with opencv and then stream it

Comment: I can't store the video. If I'll store the video, how long I have to do that? The streaming of video will run forever.

Comment: The original video is not unlimited, right? So, why the new will be? You are streaming from a camera or from a video for example?

Comment: Later I have to use a camera which is going to record the video and stream the video to the server.

Comment: You should ask a question with your needs then. No one will be able to guess your future needs

Comment: I guess this could help: http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example/

Comment: They are encoding the frame to jpg image. Is there any other way? By the way, I tried this one too but VLC is not playing the streaming video.

Comment: The main thing is, I must use content/type video, not the image.

Comment: I could help, but please specify, _how_ are you trying to stream?  With rtsp protocol (e.g. can you stream with the command "vlc rtsp://..") or what?

Comment: Thanks, guys but I found the solution. I'm using m3u8 file to stream small ts file. I followed https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19